# How much would I save doing my own electrical rough-in?

Tags: united-states, first-time-home-buyer, home

I'm a capable and confident diy-er with some electrical experience. I'm trying to find parts of the home-building process I can do myself to save some cash when I build a house in the next couple years.

I recently saw suggestions that doing your own electrical rough-in can save you some expensive labor from your electrician. I read up on the process, basic electrical codes, etc. and I am sure I could do this myself. However, after spending some time looking around, I couldn't find anywhere that said how much you would save. I'd like to get an idea approximately (very rough) how much I would save overall.

Assume it is for a 2000 sq ft house in US valued around 250k to put us in the ballpark.

Comment: Probably get some quotes from electricians to find out. Might get better answers on https://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @HartCO I thought to ask there but I'm pretty sure this question would be off topic. Not supposed to ask about how much things cost. Also, I *could* ask an electrician... or I could get a ballpark from someone online before I go to that trouble.

Comment: Feels off-topic here too, at least on DIY you'd hit some electricians who might answer/comment even if closed. You could ask if it's worth DIY'ing, which might help.

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say "when I build a house in the next couple years"? Will you be the general contractor? will you be hiring a general contractor? Will you be going to a custom builder?

Comment: The savings will likely differ based on location and on the economy at the time. Housing starts are booming--labor prices will be higher. We're in a downturn, more likely to get a deal because there's less available work.

Comment: @mhoran_psrep I'm considering being the general contractor. I've worked on enough construction sites to know that that might be difficult though since I've never done it.